# Pandas dataframe values and row condition both depend on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, slice

I have a Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','a','b','b'],
                   'col2': [1,2,3,4],
                   'col3': [11,12,13,14]})
  col1 col2 col3
0   a   1   11
1   a   2   12
2   b   3   13
3   b   4   14
```

I need to replace an entry in `col2` by some function of the row's `col2` and `col3` values if the value in `col1` is a `b`, but leave the rows unchanged if the value in `col1` is not a `b`. Say the function is `col3 * exp(col2)`, then applying this to `df` above would yield

```
    col1   col2   col3
0   a      1      11
1   a      2      12
2   b      261.1  13
3   b      764.4  14
```

Ideally this would be vectorised and in-place as my real DataFrame has a few million rows.

This differs from other questions on Stack Overflow as they only require either the new value to not depend on other columns or to change all rows at once. Thank you.

Edit: Corrected the target DataFrame. Had changed the function from `exp(col2)+col3` to `exp(col2)*col3` without updating the values in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.where` does the job:

```py
df.col2 = np.where(df.col1 == "b", df.col3 * np.exp(df.col2), df.col2)
```

It says "for each row: if `df` has `'b'` in `col1`, then take the value from 2nd argument (which is the function of `col2` and `col3`); if not, then take the value from 3rd argument (which is `col2` so it keeps as is).". Applies it to each row in a vectorized fashion.

to get

```
  col1       col2  col3
0    a    1.00000    11
1    a    2.00000    12
2    b  261.11198    13
3    b  764.37410    14
```

Comment: Thank you! Is np.where faster than pd.loc?

Comment: Quickly benchmarked on 10**7 rows: np.where took 1.66 seconds, dp.loc took 2.42 seconds, so quite similar but accepted the np.where answer for being faster.

Comment: @Connor_Tracy Glad to be of help! Yes usually there might be some speedups in the numpy domain, though not so much in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DataFrame.iloc`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col3': [11, 12, 13, 14]})

df.loc[df['col1'] == 'b', 'col2'] = df['col3'] * np.exp(df['col2'])
print(df)
```

Giving the correct

```
  col1       col2  col3
0    a    1.00000    11
1    a    2.00000    12
2    b  261.11198    13
3    b  764.37410    14
```

Comment: Thank you! Values have been corrected in the target DataFrame. Had changed the function from exp(col2)+col3 to exp(col2)*col3 without updating the values in the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','a','b','b'],
                   'col2': [1,2,3,4],
                   'col3': [11,12,13,14]})

def get_exp(col1, col2, col3):
    if col1 == 'b':
        return (col3 * np.exp(col2))
    return col2    


df.col2 = df.apply(lambda x: get_exp(x.col1, x.col2, x.col3), axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   a   1.00000     11
1   a   2.00000     12
2   b   261.11198   13
3   b   764.37410   14
```